# Running bootRun and use a different application.properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I'd like to be able to run bootRun for spring boot, but use a different application.properties file besides the one in `src/main/resources/`. Is that possible? I'd prefer to not overwrite the file in `src/main/resources/`, as it would dirty the file.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command,

```
./gradlew bootRun --args='--spring.profiles.active=dev'
```

I too was looking for the solution, found it in official documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#running-your-application

Answer (score 1):

You can use profile based configuration selection.
Just set a system environment property:

`spring.profiles.active=dev`

And  now provide application-dev.properties in application resources(`src/main/resources/`)
By this way you can use different properties for different environment.

If you want to provide files at a different location the use this environment property

`spring.config.location=<path>`

If you wish to use different name then application in property file name the  use this environment property:
`spring.config.name=<new_name>`

For more info check this link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: Is it possible to specify the profile on the comamnd line when running gradle? I'd like to avoid requiring developers to set up a system property.

Comment: You can provide file location in `spring.config.location` as environment property or can provide as java vm argument.

Comment: I have not used gradle, but I am sure there can be a way to provide java vm argument.

Comment: Like while running spring boot jar through command line, you can provide java vm argument like this: `java -Dspring.config.location=<path> -jar <spring boot jar>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what my `bootRun` task looks like that does this

```
bootRun {
    systemProperty "spring.config.location", "file:$projectDir/spring-config/"
    main = springBootAppClass
}
```

Which specifies to use the spring-config directory in the project's root folder.

If using in conjunction with `@PropertySource` it looks like this

```java
@PropertySource("${spring.config.location}/persistence.properties")
```

Comment: Hmm, I can't get this to work. It always complains about whatever I put behind the "main =". I tried it with the `springBootAppClass` from the above example, as well as with my app's main class and a number of variations thereof. What does need to go there?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this:

```
tasks.named("bootRun") {
    systemProperty "spring.config.location", "file:$projectDir/myConfigFolder"
    mainClass = "my.project.MyMainClass"
}
```